# Using repository class methods inside twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, symfony-2.1

In a Symfony2.1 project, how to call custom entity functions inside template? To elaborate, think the following scenario; there are two entities with Many-To-Many relation: User and Category.

Doctrine2 have generated such methods:

```
$user->getCategories();
$category->getUsers();
```

Therefore, I can use these in twig such as:

```
{% for category in categories %}
   <h2>{{ category.name }}</h2>
   {% for user in category.users %}
      {{ user.name }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But how can I get users with custom functions? For example, I want to list users with some options and sorted by date like this:

```
{% for user in category.verifiedUsersSortedByDate %}
```

I wrote custom function for this inside UserRepository.php class and tried to add it into Category.php class to make it work. However I got the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of
>   a template ("Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct(),

Answer (score 3):

It's much cleaner to retrieve your `verifiedUsersSortedByDate` within the controller directly and then pass it to your template.

```
//...
 $verifiedUsersSortedByDate = $this->getYourManager()->getVerifiedUsersSortedByDate();

return $this->render(
    'Xxx:xxx.xxx.html.twig',
    array('verifiedUsersSortedByDate' => $verifiedUsersSortedByDate)
);
```

You should be very carefull not to do extra work in your entities. As quoted in the doc, "An entity is a basic class that holds the data". Keep the work in your entities as basic as possible and apply all the "logic" within the `entityManagers`.

If you don't want get lost in your code, it's best to follow this kind of format, in order (from Entity to Template)

```
1 - Entity. (Holds the data)

2 - Entity Repositories. (Retrieve data from database, queries, etc...)

3 - Entity Managers (Perform crucial operations where you can use some functions from your repositories as well as other services.....All the logic is in here! So that's how we can judge if an application id good or not)

4 - Controller(takes request, return responses by most of the time rendering a template)

5 - Template (render only!)
```

Comment: Actually, you are wrong about logic. Entities -are- the only place that should contains logic. If you are to put logic in controllers, you are going to see big messy code with lots of repetition.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Zelijko. I never said controllers though... Entities only hold the metadata. To quote the doc "It is a basic class that holds data". You need to use entity managers to work on this data, and apply the business logic there. I give you the point that the term logic on its ensemble refers to entity+entityManager+services that allow treating the data. I have clarified my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the users inside your controller via repository

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$verifiedusers = $em->getRepository('MYBundle:User')->getVerifiedUsers();
```

---

```
 return array(
            'verifiedusers'      => $verifiedusers,
                   );
    }
```